# Arithmetic Syntax Error when running a script in RedHat OS

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I am encountering a problem when I try to run a script in RedHat OS. I get an arithmetic syntax error.

[image]

Now here's the script that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo ""
echo " = K+WA =";
WA_PORT="`cat /usr/kplushome/entities/Standalone/config/kondor.active |grep PORTAL_PORT|cut -d '&' -f 2`"

#== Checking Tomcat of WebAccess
printf "%25s" Tomcat
touch /usr/kplushome/entities/Standalone/config/webaccess/WebaccessDomainTomcat/bin/tomcat-*.pid
PID=`cat /usr/kplushome/entities/Standalone/config/webaccess/WebaccessDomainTomcat/bin/tomcat-*.pid`
if [[ $PID = "" ]];then
echo " x 0"
else
PSPID=`/bin/ps -eo pid | grep -w $PID`
if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]];then
/bin/ps -ef | grep $PID | grep -v grep | awk 'NR==1 {print " = "$8 $9 $10 $11 $12 $13 $14 $15}'
else
echo " x 0"
fi
fi

PORT_STATUS=`netstat -an | grep ${WA_PORT} | grep LISTEN | perl -pe "s/^.+\n/LISTENING/g;"`
PORT_STATUS=${PORT_STATUS:="NOT LISTENING!!!"}
echo " Port ${WA_PORT}/TCP = ${PORT_STATUS}"

cd /usr/kplushome/entities/Standalone/config/webaccess/WebaccessServer/etc
(PATH=/usr/ucb:$PATH; ./checkall.sh;) | perl -pe "s,^, ,g;"
echo ""
```

Problem is I don't see anything wrong with my line 15 as I don't see any rule from unix that was violated for it to have an arithmetic syntax error, or am I missing something? May I ask for any advice from you experts? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could be that any of `$PSPID` or `$PID` is empty at line 15 at script runtime?

Comment: that I am not sure, is there a way for me to check whether line 15 is empty at script runtime or not? please help, thank you!

Comment: Put an echo at line 14: `echo "PSPID is:$PSPID and PID is:$PID"`. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows two numbers. These seem to be process ids. A likely answer is that your line

```
PID=`cat /usr/kplushome/entities/Standalone/config/webaccess/WebaccessDomainTomcat/bin/tomcat-*.pid`
```

is finding 2 files and you are getting these 2 pids set in the variable, separated by a newline. When used in `if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]]` you will have 2 numbers after the `-eq`, which is the syntax error.

You should doublequote your variables (eg `"$PID"`) to avoid this type of syntax error, though clearly the real problem is that you had 2 numbers instead of 1. Depending on what is legal for your situation, you could simply add a loop handling each pid separately (`for pid in $PID`...).

Comment: Hi meuh, should I double quote all the `$PID` in my script or just the `$PID` from this line: `if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]]` ?? thank you

Comment: am I supposed to double quote only the `$PID` in the `if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]]` ? Or should I do it with all the `$PID` in the script. thanks

Comment: Good practice is to always double quote all variables when they are used, to avoid whitespace in the value causing it to be split into separate words, so quote PSPID and PID to avoid syntax errors.  However, in some cases you know the value consists of many words and you want to split them, as in this example where you wouldn't quote `for pid in $PID` if you use it.

Comment: I think you're first assessment is correct, there were two files with `tomcat-` at the beginning of their filenames that were saved in the system namely tomcat-.pid and tomcat-KOPL58IRA02.pid. I plan to remove the wildcard `*` in line 10 so instead of `tomcat-*.pid` I will change it to `tomcat-.pid` so that it will only access one file. Do you think my solution will solve the problem? I'm asking right now since I do not have the machine at the moment so I cannot test it currently

Comment: I forgot to mention, those two files contain the same process id: 1743 so it's a bit clever why they are separate files when they just contain the same thing :)

Comment: Your example shows 2 different pids in the error message (if it wasnt a screenshot I'd copy/paste the text here). Perhaps one of the files was very old, created when you were still testing? If both files have the same age and contents, then clearly you can remove the wildcard `*` and just use one of the files.

Comment: Okay thanks, may I know why the age of the file matters? And Yes, these two files have the same contents. Both of them contains  the 1743 value as their process id.

Comment: This assessment helped me pin point the problem, different solution from mine but none the less this helped me solve the issue. Thank you @meuh

Answer (score 1):

Lines 14 and 15 of the script are:

```
PSPID=`/bin/ps -eo pid | grep -w $PID`
if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]];then
```

If you're getting an error on line 15, the most likely cause is that either `PSPID` or `PID` is undefined, likely resulting in an effective line 15 of something like:

```
if [[ -eq 12345 ]];then
```

which would be a syntactical error.  You can mitigate this by quoting your variables (e. g. `"$PID"` rather than `$PID`).

As an aside, it's helpful to see what's going on as your script runs.  It does munge the output a bit, but for problematic sections of your script, prefix what's misbehaving with `set -x` and your standard output will now include command-by-command what is being sent to the shell that's running the script.

Comment: hi expert, how should I do that prefix? is it supposed to be like this: `set -x if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]];then` ?? thanks

Comment: `set -x` would be on its own line before the `if` block, and then `set +x` later to turn it back off.